# Simulink function block reusable and editable

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

I would like to create something as a subsystem (let's call it block B), that I could use and, when I edit it, it could update every block B in my model.

I'd like to create something like a mask that I could reuse and edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for two different features of simulink:

1. Library

   Mathworks-Documentation: [Working with linked blocks](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/ug/creating-and-working-with-linked-blocks.html)

   To edit a block "somewhere" you have to disable the link, make your changes and resolve the link again. After updating you model (ctrl+d) or updating the links (ctrl+k) the updated lib content is in every instance of the lib.
2. Masking of Blocks

   Mathworks-Documentation: [Simulink masking](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/masking.html)

   Masking has nothing to do with libs. But you can mix up both features.